# batch; Save input as option for next run (livestreamer)

Tags: batch-file

I created my first batch file ever a couple of weeks ago to use livestreamer more comfortably.

Basically I can either type in the name of Twitch streamer or I can start something from another plattform.

What I am trying to do is is save my input as an option for the next time.

Let's say I went to the twitch stream of "shroud". When the stream ends I would like to put shroud as an option in the beginning of the script:

```
:start
title twitchings
color 0a
echo Select [#] or enter Stream
echo.
echo 1. non twitch
echo 2. shroud
set /p select=?
```

I assume it would be easiest to store that list in a txt file and then load it upon running the batch file, but my basically non-existant knowledge in coding hinders me from creating it.
Does anyone know a quick help, I would also love to know if there is a website where I can learn this stuff without googling for hours :)

This is my updated script for those who are searching for the same issue.

```
@ECHO off

:start
title twitchings
color 0a
echo Select [#] or enter Stream
echo.
echo 1. non twitch

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=C:\Users\[...]\savedstreams.txt"
set /A i=1
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
set /a i += 1
echo !i! . %%a
)

set /p select=?

set /a varCheck=%select%
if %varCheck% == %select% (goto :isnumber) else (goto :isstream)
exit /B

:isnumber 
set "lineNr=%select%"
set /a lineNr-=1+1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`more +%lineNr% savedstreams.txt`) DO (
  set "stream=%%a"
  goto :leave
)
:leave
set "stream=%stream:*:=%"
echo stream: %stream%
goto qual

:isstream
set "stream=%select%"
echo %stream% >>savedstreams.txt
goto qual

:TpyeInSource
echo enter URL
echo.
set /p select2=?  
livestreamer %select2%
GOTO end

:qual
livestreamer http://twitch.tv/%stream% 1080p60 || livestreamer http://twitch.tv/%stream% best
GOTO end

:end
@CHOICE /C:rqn /M "[R]etry, [Q]uit or [N]ew"
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO start
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO quit
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO qual
GOTO quit

:quit
echo "bye."
@PAUSE
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: What will the goto options be for the likes of any new option? It must go somewhere, so how do you plan on doing that?

Comment: I am very new to this, so I am working one step at a time.
I now finished my script. I am basically reading out each line of the txt file. Then I use the select method to chose the exact line in the text file. Give that line to a variable which then opens the stream.
I updated my script in my main post. It works pretty well so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use >> to put the output of a command in text file. For example:

```
echo hi everyone >>textfile.txt
```

will add "hi everyone" to the last line of the text file.
You can also use > to add it to the first line instead.

Comment: Thank you. This was the hint I needed to get a step further.